# Simple login with no database Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok am extending an existing codeigniter site but need to hide the new part behind a login so is not seen early by mistake. The issue I have is I have no database to store the data and my attempts so far have been in vain to get this working. I basically need to hide all pages controlled by 1 controller unless the user enters the correct password. I have no issue of storing the username/password (as there will only be 1) in an array or xml as is more a case of hiding this part of the site from existing customers until we are ready to release (we do however have to show to a few select people).

This is my current controller if anyone could help me would be very much appreciated:

```
<?php

class ClassName extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($classname = 'latestvideos') {

        if (!file_exists('../application/views/ClassName/' . $classname . '.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }       
        $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/headings.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/links.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/footer.php');
        $this->lang->load('ClassName/' . $classname . '.php');        

        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newheader');
        $this->load->view('ClassName/' . $classname);
        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newfooter');
    }
}
```

There will be about 9 pages run from this controller so I am guessing I need to add a login in the header and use an if statement to say if logged in show the page. I had this working in on a plain php page but cannot get this to work in codeigniter and the examples I have seen either do not work or are incomplete so please help my knowledge of php and codeigniter is limited so would appreciate step by step guide. Thanks

Comment: Do not have access or allowed to put one on the server

Comment: I can run DB for you on my server (france) if you want.
See also my own user system with refferals:

https://github.com/jakon89/UserSystemCodeIgniter

Comment: If it was my own project I can run the db no problem on my server my hands are tied here. I need to find a solution without a db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Controller

```
class ClassName extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('session');
     $this->load->helper('url');
}
public function index($classname = 'latestvideos') {

    if(!$this->session->userdata('custom_login')=='true'){
       show_404();
    }
//everything you want to do if the user is logged in
}
public function show_login(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('custom_login')=='true'){
        $this->load->view('the_form_view');
        }
else{
 redirect('classname');
}

public function post_login(){
 $my_password_value='something';
    if($this->input->post('my_custom_password') && $this->input->post('my_custom_password')==$my_password_value){
       $this->session->set_userdata('custom_login','true');
redirect('classname');
    }
}
```

The view

```
<form method="POST" action="classname/post_login">
<label for="password">Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" name="my_custom_password" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Notice that the above is not much safe.

Though it would be better in your occasion to add an ftp password protection through .htaccess for that controller file, or folder.

Comment: its an iis server so no .htaccess, and also its running as a subdomain inside a codeigniter app so can't actually put a folder password on as would affect the rest of the site.

Comment: Thanks for this what would I need to add to the view to get this to work thanks

Comment: Just create a hidden route that you can access manually, by writing the path on the url, so it is not public accessible. Like mysite.com/myspecial_login. THen there add a form that posts the password , you want to authenticate, and if it passes the checks store the user custom_login in session

Comment: Gives the following error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in ClassName.php on line 9 line 9 being: $this->session->set_userdata('custom_login')=true;

Comment: There were some quotes added in the code from stackoverflow, copy again and if($this->input->post('my_custom_password') && $this->input->post('my_custom_password')==$my_password_value){ have it in one line to be sure

Comment: ok now getting: PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in CLassName.php on line 7 line 7 being the same as last time. Is that because I have not added a form on the view or something else?

Comment: Sorry still no joy PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in line 6

Comment: have you set $mycustom_value='something' before the if statement?

Comment: I just copied and pasted so public function index($class = 'latestvideos') {
     if(isset($this->input->post('my_custom_password')) && $this->input->post('my_custom_password')==$my_password_value){
       $this->session->set_userdata('custom_login')=true;
    }
    if(!$this->session->userdata('custom_login')==true){
       show_404();
    }

        if (!file_exists('../application/views/' . $class . '.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }  
  $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/headings.php');....

Comment: Could you put the entire controller with your code as I said my php/codeigniter knowledge is not great

Comment: In your question you said "I basically need to hide all pages controlled by 1 controller unless the user enters the correct password". so you have to set the $my_password_value before the if statements. See my edit.

Comment: ok copied that but still getting: PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context on line 8 = if(isset($this->input->post('my_custom_password')) && $this->input->post('my_custom_password')==$my_password_value){

Comment: ok sorry i did a big mistake in $this->session->set_userdata, i edited the code. it's been a long time since i wrote code in CI :P

Comment: ok getting PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object on line 13 = if(!$this->session->userdata('custom_login')=='true'){ I really appriciae your help in this hopefully will get there soon :)

Comment: it seems that you haven't load the session library. You can load it here with $this->load->library('session');

Comment: ok cool now get page not found so just need to do page with the form correct? any chance you can help me with this as have no idea how to pass session details etc.

Comment: I think you are O.K. to go now, I cannot help you more, from here because I am not your freelancer :P . Vote the answers if you had help from anyone.

Comment: Ok thanks am at least on the right track now thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using:

```
<?php

class ClassName extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($classname = 'latestvideos') {

        if (!file_exists('../application/views/ClassName/' . $classname . '.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }       
        $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/headings.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/links.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/footer.php');
        $this->lang->load('ClassName/' . $classname . '.php');        

        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newheader');
        $this->load->view('ClassName/' . $classname);
        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newfooter');
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
<?php

class ClassName extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
         $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/headings.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/links.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/footer.php');
        $this->lang->load('ClassName/index.php');        

        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newheader');
        $this->load->view('ClassName/index.php');
        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newfooter');

    }

    public function latestvideos()
    {
         $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/headings.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/links.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/footer.php');
        $this->lang->load('ClassName/latestvideos.php');        

        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newheader');
        $this->load->view('ClassName/latestvideos.php');
        $this->load->view('templates/common/Newfooter');

    }
```

It is more flexible and more efective.

You can create file at registration and next make nick.xml file with password and other record.
At login you have to find file nick.xml, parse it and check if password=input password. If yes then set session and redirect.

You can filter privileges in class contstructor to verify user privileges.

(example form my script)

```
private $forbidden_for_registered = array('register', 'login', 'setnewpassword', 'newpassword', 'confirm');
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if(TRUE === $this->session->has_userdata('userid') || TRUE === $this->session->has_userdata('nick'))
    {
         if ('ClassName' == $this->uri->rsegment(1) && in_array($this->uri->rsegment(2), $this->forbidden_for_registered))
            show_404();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used my method as that is what is in the codeigniter tutorial: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: Are you doing statis page or not ?

Comment: yes i am using static pages hence my use from the tutorial